# Difference between Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set and Azure Batch

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch

I am new to Azure. Does anyone know the basic difference between VMSS and Azure Batch. I have studied the material on the Microsoft website, and there indeed is a difference, but the terms are complicated for me as a beginner. Can anyone please explain the difference in simple terms along with an example?

MANY THANKS.

Answer (score -1):

Azure VM Scale Set is intended to scale in and scale out your VM.

**For example**: if we have VM A which runs our application and we start experiencing load, then if VM A is part of a scale set, Azure will spin up another VM (VM B) with the same application, so the load is distributed. When the load reduces, VM B will be "removed". The scale set gave you elasticity.
Example for using a scale set - we have a service that handles user registrations for a web application.

Azure Batch is intended for a different purpose.
First, a VM is always up and have some application running on it. With Azure Batch we are interested in performing a compute-intensive task and distribute the calculations across the nodes in the batch.

**For example**, run a daily job that requires 60 VMs to perform in a reasonable time. After the job finished, the VMs are deallocated.
Note that Azure batch is not a good fit for the user registration service - as this is something that takes many small request, not computation

So Azure batch is a service that spins off VMs, it can manage them (e.g what if one node fails) and a specific task that requires high computing power is run.

Comment: Sorry Belgi, as a beginner, this explanation is quite complicated for me. Can you please explain a little bit more in simple words? --Thanks.